# Centering text field in Titanium Mobile

Tags: javascript, textfield, center, titanium-mobile

How do I center a text field in Titanium? Here's the text field code:

```
var textfield1 = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#006',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    height:50,
    top:'auto',
    left:'auto',
    width:300,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your parent uses a vertical layout, it's auto centered. 'auto' top will be 0 ; remove your left.
You can also use textAlign : 'center' in other layouts.